# Edit binding IIS 8 by C# or by appcmd

Tags: c#, iis, appcmd

How do you modify an existing binding in a configured Site in IIS 8 (Windows 8)? I'm trying to do it by the command prompt.

I can add a new binding by command prompt running as administrator mode:

```
> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set site /site.name:test /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:mitest']
```

In command prompt I use:

```
> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set site "test" /?
```

To see the SET Binding options, and are not exist a command as "SET Binding BY BINDING ID".

By C# code I use:

```
string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");    
string comando = windir +"\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe set site /site.name:test /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:mitest']";

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + comando);

procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;                
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine(result);
Debug.WriteLine(result);
```

And I get the Error: **"Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"**

But I can't modify by command. And I can't create binding by code for next step try modify it.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the question is old, i will answer this because i had the same issue and found the following working solution with the APPCMD tool. This Example shows how to add a Host-Header to an existing SSL-Binding.

```
appcmd set site /site.name "SiteName" /bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:*'].BindingInformation:*:443:NewHostHeader
```

Comment: Today i needed to slightly modify the above CMD. One star in the existing binding had to be removed to work...      `appcmd set site /site.name "SiteName" /bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:'].BindingInformation:*:443:NewHostHeader`

Answer (score 1):

I answer myself, after reviewing the issue for hours. I read that using appcmd by c# code is very complicated because permissions. Finally I used the **ServerManager** class, first I reference this dll in my project:

**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll**

then I use the code to manipulate the AppPools, Sites or Bindings. The binding not have a ID then you can use a HashTable, in my case "bindingNameBase", to mantain keys with the hostname (are uniques in my project/problem) so It:

```
public void EditBinding(int id, SiteBinding siteBinding, string newKeyName)
        {
            using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                if (serverManager.Sites == null)
                    return;

                for (int i = 0; i < serverManager.Sites.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (serverManager.Sites[i].Id == id)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection bindingCollection = serverManager.Sites[i].Bindings;

                        // se elimina el binding
                        Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding bindingTmp = null;
                        for (int j = 0; j < bindingCollection.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (bindingCollection[j].Host == bindingNameBase[newKeyName].ToString())
                            {
                                bindingTmp = bindingCollection[j];                                
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (bindingTmp != null)
                        {
                            bindingCollection.Remove(bindingTmp);

                            //se crea de nuevo
                            Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding binding = serverManager.Sites[i].Bindings.CreateElement("binding");
                            binding["protocol"] = siteBinding.Protocol;
                            binding["bindingInformation"] = string.Format(@"{0}:{1}:{2}", siteBinding.IPAddress, siteBinding.Port.ToString(), siteBinding.HostName);

                            bool existe = false;
                            for (int j = 0; j < bindingCollection.Count; j++)
                            {
                                if (bindingCollection[j].Host == siteBinding.HostName)
                                {
                                    existe = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (existe == false)
                            {
                                bindingCollection.Add(binding);
                                serverManager.CommitChanges();

                                bindingNameBase[newKeyName] = siteBinding.HostName;
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                }
```

The Site must by use a Pool with correct identity, or you have problems with permissions.